# iOS set/change background image on load

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have to make som changes to a iPhone app...

How can i change the background on a UIViewController on load (viewDidLoad) .. I have to show a .png from a URL .. Is that posible?

I have tried:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_to_my_project/xmas-bg-test.png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

this is from my : "- (void)viewDidLoad" method .. Nothing happend when I start my app.. no errors ether.

I have also tried from my .. viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `UIImageView` as a background image. Remove `self.view.backgroundColor = ...` line and add this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

in `viewDidLoad:` method.

Comment: Thanks, I a noob ;) .. I already have i UTImageView with a background i want to change at the load - in my .xib file .. Does it make sense?

Comment: just set the `image` property of `UIImageView` to your new image: `imageView.image = image;`

Comment: I have tried that, but nothing happens .. How do I know that the imageview is the one i have created in my .xib file .. i'm brand new to this .. Why is where no ID to set on a imageview? ..

Comment: you have to [connect ImageView to your IBOutlet in IB](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/CreatingOutlet.html). Here is [another tutorial](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/10/28/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/).

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you add a background to a view controller. Add a new [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ivar to your view controller subclass and use that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

You have to make sure you create this image view properly. Either by adding an image view in Interface Builder and linking it to your `imageView` ivar, or by creating it yourself in `awakeFromNib` or `loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct for saying that you should be using an image view to display the image. However, you should consider making a request for the image. This way, if the request fails you can handle it by displaying a different image or what ever you want. Here's a **rough** example.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_to_my_project/xmas-bg-test.png"] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:5.0];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (response && !error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
}];
```